# Package is struck at "Execute phase is beginning" at Lookup task

Tags: ssis

I have used a Lookup in my data flow task. When I use Full Cache mode, the data flow task runs fine. But when I use Partial Cache or no Cache in my lookup, the records do not go past the lookup task and it keeps running for hours. I have checked for errors but there aren't any errors displayed. Could anyone please help me on this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not enough information. What is the lookup doing and are there any parameters? Note: if you are not using any parameters then use full cache mode. The other two are for if you are using parameters.

Comment: There aren't any parameters and I'm using lookup based on the primary key columns at the target to perform Incremental Load. There are almost 27 million records that I want to move from the source to the target table(currently empty). Full cache wouldn't cause any problems during the first load but will cause memory issues from the next load. My requirement is that I want records to be inserted from the source that do not exist in the target table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Lookup is not appropriate for your task. Instead:

1. Add an OLE DB Source to pull in the data
2. Sort the records from the incoming source and the OLE DB Source
3. Perform a merge join (Full outer).
4. Add a Derived Column Transformation to check for ISNULL on the two joining columns. Create a new output column Called Action. For the NULLs in the target then you will tag that as an INSERT record.
5. Add a conditional split to send the INSERT record to an OLE DB Destination to insert the new records.

You can also check to see if there are matches between the two populations and perform updates, or look for NULLs in the source and DELETE in the destination.

Comment: Thanks J Weezy. Did the same and now it works a lot faster.